# OEM Office 2003 without media - how to reinstall?

Tags: reinstall, microsoft-office-2003

I'm re-installing windows and I found that I don't have the install disk for my office 2003 (standard edition). I extracted my CD key before the re-install. Where can I find an iso or installer so I can re-install office?

There is a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/229718/oem-office-2010-without-media-how-to-reinstall) for office 2010 but Microsoft doesnt seem to have anything similar available for office 2003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download it here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/2/3/6233A257-16BD-4C8D-BF4C-6FA59AF9213A/OfficeSTD.exe

Answer (score 1):

Contact Microsoft's Supplemental Parts team, they will replace the media for most products, or at least tell you your options. :)

They have a knowledge base article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326246

"How to replace Microsoft software or hardware, order service packs, and replace product manuals"

> Contact information
>
> In the United States and Canada, you can reach the Microsoft Supplemental Parts team at the contact numbers that are listed here:
>
> United States: (800) 360-7561, Monday through Friday, 5:00 A.M. to 7:00 P.M. Pacific Time.
>
> Canada: (800) 933-4750, Monday through Friday, 5:00 A.M. to 7:00 P.M. Pacific Time.
>
> TTY customers: Contact Microsoft at (800) 718-1599, Monday through Friday, 5:00 A.M. to 7:00 P.M. Pacific Time.

You can use that KB article to locate your local contact if outside North America.