# OEM Office 2003 Professional without media - how to reinstall?

Tags: microsoft-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OEM Office 2003 without media - how to reinstall?](https://superuser.com/questions/316576/oem-office-2003-without-media-how-to-reinstall)

I want to install Microsoft Office 2003 Professional on a new computer. I have the license Key, but not the installation CD. Can I find the download somewhere? I would like to stress that it should be the Professional Edition, not the Standard Edition.