# Keep OEM MS Office after reinstalling Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, oem

I have a HP G62-355DX Laptop that came with Windows 7 and Office 2007 pre-installed. I'm planning to reformat the HDD to fix slowdown and other various issues that have begun to crop up, but I'm not sure how I can do that and keep my MS Office suite.

I'm planning to just do a Factory Reset using the HP Recovery Manager utility, explained  [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&dlc=en&docname=c01867418&lc=en&product=4308434&tmp_track_link=ot_search).

The support page says that the process will re-install the original software, but I don't know if that includes MS Office. That question and its answer are conspicuously absent from HP's forums and help pages, so I'm beginning to think that Office will not be re-installed automatically.

I read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/229718/oem-office-2010-without-media-how-to-reinstall) that the trial version of Office could be downloaded from Microsoft's website and then upgraded to the full version with the license key. The only license key I have is the one on the sticker on the bottom of the laptop, which is for Windows. If I need to re-download the software, is this same key used for my Office license? Also, can I even download Office 2007 from Microsoft anymore?

Comment: You will have to determine the license key in the event office is not reinstalled.  We cannot predict if it will be reinstalled that entirely depends on what the image contains.

Answer (score 0):

Won't let me comment so adding as an answer: you may be able to obtain the media from HP if you don't have media. Also, if it came with Office 2007 preinstalled by HP, then they have to have provided you with a licence key for Office 2007 as well as for Windows. That is, if the Office 2007 installation wasn't just a trial installation that they loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out about the product keys of the installed programs on your computer download the following application (it is a freeware app). [Magical Jelly Bean](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/)